# Requests and handlers in swift

Tags: swift, request

I need to get data from url. For it I have get method in "HTTPClient" class.

```
func getRequest(url: String, parameters: String = "", completion: (NSData) -> ()) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    if parameters != "" {
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url + "?" + parameters)!)
    }
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = true

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            completion(data!)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

But when I call it from "MainService" class I don't get data in handler. (I don't come in handler)

```
func getAvailableCoins() -> [Coin]? {
    var coins = [Coin]?()

    httpClient.getRequest("http://shapeshift.io/getcoins", completion: { data in
        coins = self.shapeShiftService.availableCoins(data)
    })

    return coins
}
```

What problem can be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that you return from your getAvailableCoins() method BEFORE your handler gets a chance to be called. Consequently you return an empty array.

So basically the thing is that getAvailableCoins() is an asynchronous operation and you can't use **return** statement to return result. What you could do is declare a special method and call it when your coins are fetched:

```
func getAvailableCoins() {
    var coins = [Coin]?()

    httpClient.getRequest("http://shapeshift.io/getcoins", completion: { data in
        coins = self.shapeShiftService.availableCoins(data)
        coinsAreReady(coins)
    })
}

func coinsAreReady(coins: [Coin]?) {
    //do what you need with your coins here
}
```

Now **coinsAreReady** will be called when your data is loaded and you can work with it from there.

Comment: But how take more time for handler?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your handler is called not immediately but later after the operation with network has been completed. That's the point of using a handler.

Comment: I know that it working not immediately, but how can I get data, and then call shapeShiftService.availableCoins(data) ?

Comment: No problem in error != nil. I get data without problems